# Finding 19th-century passenger arrivals to the United States

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, immigration

My great-grandfather Aloysius Deckert was born in Germany and died in Albany, New York in 1901.

How can I find his arrival in the United States?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  Have you checked the censuses for him?  Please edit your question to include all the information you already have to help people avoid telling you what you already know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  I've edited your question to move information into the question body & made the title more specifc. If you have questions about how the site works, you can find information in the [help] and on the site's companion [Meta] site. A checklist of sources you have on hand is useful -- we may be able to point out clues that you have missed.